# Parsing multiple lists in HTML file with Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, hash, html-parsing, nokogiri

I'm trying to learn scripting with Ruby, and this is my first problem.

I have an HTML file which contains states and their cities. I need to be able to access the cities and know which state they belong to in my Ruby code, **so I plan on parsing the HTML and creating a hash for each city, like this: {New York => New York City}.**

I'm attempting to use Nokogiri, which I'm just learning now.

```
  <h4>State</h4>
  <ul>
    <li>city</li>
    <li>city</li>
    <li>city</li>
  </ul>
  <h4>State</h4>
  <ul>
    <li>city</li>
    <li>city</li>
    <li>city</li>
  </ul>
  <h4>State</h4>
  <ul>
    <li>city</li>
    <li>city</li>
    <li>city</li>
  </ul>
```

I'm using this to get the states into an array:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'

page = Nokogiri::HTML(open("to_parse.html"))

states = Array.new(100), index = 0

page.css('h4').each do |s|

    states[index]   = s.text
    puts states[index]

    index += 1
end
```

This actually doesn't really help; I need to figure out how I can get `Nokogiri` to parse the elements of each list into `hashes` containing the city and its state. I'm not sure how to have a loop break when it finishes the city list of one state, and create a new set of `hashes` for the city list of the next state.

I'm thinking I'll have to create a `hash` for each list element and store the text of the `h4` tag for that list inside each `hash`, so I know which state the city belongs to. Which is what I'm not sure how to do.

Feel free to offer some advice on refactoring what I've got, as I know it could be done better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XPath selectors can help you out here.

```
states = doc.css('li').map do |city|
  state = city.xpath('../preceding-sibling::h4[1]')
  [city.text, state.text]
end.to_h

#=> {'city' => 'State', ...}
```

This grabs all the `li` city elements, then traces back to their state. (the XPath reads like so: `..` = up one level, `preceding-sibling::h4` = the preceding `h4` elements, `[1]` = the first such element)

Some comments on your code: In Ruby, you don't need to initialize arrays, and with the [Enumerable](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Enumerable.html) methods like `map` you never need to track index variables in loops.

Note that the final `to_h` only works in Ruby 2.1 or greater.

Comment: Thanks, working perfectly. And yah, I didn't think I was using the right type of iteration. Thanks for the advice.